# Webpack does not load "asset/resource" type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

I've been trying to use Webpack in an electron-forge app to load assets (images, specifically) but I haven't succeeded.

The main issue is that when I use the example rule for png with "asset/resource" as a type, the app won't run and an error gets thrown.

My rules are as follows:

```
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource'
  }
];
```

The error that gets thrown is the following:

```
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[3].type should be one of these:
   "javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
   -> Module type to use for the module
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[3].type should be one of these:
   "javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
   -> Module type to use for the module
    at webpack (C:\Users\Iscle\Documents\Work\TFG\gestishop-forge\node_modules\@electron-forge\plugin-webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
    at C:\Users\Iscle\Documents\Work\TFG\gestishop-forge\node_modules\@electron-forge\plugin-webpack\src\WebpackPlugin.ts:236:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Iscle\Documents\Work\TFG\gestishop-forge\node_modules\@electron-forge\plugin-webpack\src\WebpackPlugin.ts:235:13
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've searched for similar errors and nothing comes up. The rule is copied directly from the official documentation (https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). The webpack version being used is the latest one available as of right now.

I'm out of ideas now, maybe somebody with more experience can shine some light.

Thanks!

Comment: you should check this npm package out, ```copy-webpack-plugin```, I use it to deal with assets...saves me the pain of setting rules up and just copies...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest version of webpack installed using:

`npm: npm install webpack@latest`

`Yarn: yarn add webpack@latest`

You may be on version 4 currently, the default download (at least on npm) seems to be version 4 as of this post. This helped me just now, I hope it helps!

https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/